# Can't type anything while running code in netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

Ok so I'm having troubles with netbeans. When I run the code I can't type anything, i can only paste something and that's annoying. Let's just have a very simple example, here's the code:

```
    #include <iostream>

int main() {
    int number;
    std::cout << "Give me a number: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> number;
    std::cout << "You gave me " << number << ". Thank you." << std::endl;
}
```

Ok when I hit run it shows me "Give me number". Under that text there is a white box which becomes black when i click it and i can't type anything, so only way to move forward is copying the number and the paste it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try to change the console type :

Right click on your project > Properties > Run > Console Type

Comment: 5 years later and this is still a relevant solution (just had the same problem), what are those Netbeans people even doing with their IDE?

Answer (score 7):

Adding to Vincent's explanation, I find that the correct console type is the External Terminal.

(Given that this question was over a year ago, this is mostly for the sake of future Googlers)

Comment: I'm a future googler and Standard Output seems to be working so far

Comment: @MrRedstoner the default console still doesn't work properly when I try to type into it.

Answer (score 0):

*ProjectName* -> Properties -> Run -> Console -> Standard Output is I THINK what the original question was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me and I **solved** it using this way:

**Right click** on your project > Properties > Run > Console Type > **Standard Output**

Answer (score 0):

On your Netbeans IDE,
Right click on your Project > Properties > Run > Console Type >> Then change it to external console.

This way "cin" will work with you and record your input.